# Magento Image does not exist

Tags: magento, csv, import

i am  installing latest version of magento(1.7.0.2) when i trying magento  import csv file it shows an error image does not exist i am using the fallowing steps

1) enter data in products and export in to csv file after that entering the data in to csv file again importing

2) images are placed at `media->catalog->product->products` i tried with the different image  url  paths

```
/media/catalog/product/products/sample.jpg
/products/sample.jpg
```

3)images are also placed at `media->import` and image url paths

```
/media/import/sample.jpg
/sample.jpg
```

i tried with out image in csv file using 2nd method data will be imported 
but with image url  not able to  import the data with images

Comment: The correct folder is `media/import`. Please double check your .csv image fields that they do _not_ have leading slashes, but a relative to the `media/import` folder. Example: for the file `/media/folder/sample.jpg` the correct .csv field entry is `sample.jpg`, _not_ `/sample.jpg`.

Comment: trying with sample.jpg its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had the same problem and found [this thread](http://www.meteorify.com/2012/05/importing-product-images-csv-magento-1-7-0-0/) for the image to be imported has be `/image.jpg` without folders.

Answer (score 1):

A few additions made by my own observations:

1. When you import products with images to magento make sure, the directory media/catalog/product is empty
2. Upload your product images to the directory media/import/product/ (create it if necessary)
3. Ensure that your image-paths in the csv-file have a leading /

upload your file and get your products imported with images.

This solution worked for me, after several others failed.

(Tested on Magento 1.8.0.1)