# Image is not importing from CSV in Import Section in Magento 1.5

Tags: php, magento-1.5

any body having solution for Image import from CSV in Import Section in Magento 1.5. All the data are importing but except Image. Please help me to come up from it.
System -> Import/Export -> Import.

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045151/magento-image-does-not-exist. Although your question is more relevant at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: Thank you Rikesh for your quik reply. But i did all the stuff like copied images in media/import and made new folder as 'ABCD Product' and in CSV i have given image link as '/ABCD Product/image.jpg'. but still image is not uploading

Comment: Please help me over this...!!